# set background image gef5

Tags: java, background, zest

I'm new to GEF5.  I'm using the zest/JFace approach.  I can configure the nodes and edges as I like (fonts, background colors, icons, edge decorations, etc.) but I cannot figure out how to set the background with either an image or a color.  It appears that I'm stuck with a white background.  How do I change the properties of the background on which the nodes and edges are drawn?
Mark